# Shiro how to secure the data source password

Tags: apache-zeppelin, shiro

I have been exploring Apache Shiro with Zeppelin and so far has been able to make authentication work with JdbcRealm but one thing that is not going well is giving the data source password as plain text.

Is there a way to avoid that?

My shiro.ini looks like:

```
[main]
dataSource                    = org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource
dataSource.serverName         = localhost
dataSource.databaseName       = dp
dataSource.user               = dp_test
dataSource.password           = Password123

ps = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
pm = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
pm.passwordService = $ps

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealmCredentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher


jdbcRealm.dataSource = $dataSource
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $pm


shiro.loginUrl = /api/login

[roles]

admin = *

[urls]

/** = authc
```

Is there a way to avoid giving data source password as plain text
`dataSource.password = Password123`?

Would like to give something like:
`$shiro1$SHA-256$500000$YdUEhfDpsx9KLGeyshFegQ==$m+4wcq4bJZo1HqDAGECx50LcEkRZI0zCyq99gtRqZDk=`

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is a way, but there will still be a password lying around somewhere due to the nature of shiro needing to know the password.

### Why Hashing does not work

You posted

> something like: $shiro1$SHA-256[…]

This is a hash, and thus it is not reversible. There is no way shiro could log into the datasource using this String.

### Container managed datasources

The best approach I can recommend at this point is to have a container managed resource. A container is referring to a (web) application server in this case, like tomcat, OpenLiberty or Wildfly.

For your use case, try looking into the following:

1. extend `org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm` or `AuthorizingRealm`
2. Add the JPA API to your module and inject a persistence context like so:

```java
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
```

3. Override the methods

- `protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token)`
- `protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals)`

… to load from your managed datasource instead.

**Drawbacks of this approach:**

You just delegated datasource login to your container / application server. The server is still facing the same problems. E.g. with OpenLiberty, you will still need to store a master key of an encrypted (not hashed) password somewhere, [and thus liberty will do exactly this](https://openliberty.io/docs/20.0.0.12/password-encryption.html).

### use another configuration source

Instead of using a `shiro.ini` file, you could also write your own [environment loader](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/env/EnvironmentLoader.html). You could request the file from an IP-restricted web service or a cryptographic hardware device.

### Always a goal: restrict the environment

You should always restrict the environment.
E.g. create a user which can install, but not run your application and who cannot read the logs (called setup-user or so).
Create another user which can start the application, read but not modify configuration files and write logs, called a run-user.

Restrict access to configurations and logs for all other users on that system.

### Getting involved

If you have other needs, feel welcome to discuss other solutions on the [shiro mailing lists](https://shiro.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).